# Edit JTextPane's paintComponent() Method to change the String's color

Tags: java, swing, overriding, paintcomponent, jtextpane

I've got a JTextPane I'm looking where I can find the original paintComponent Method, so i can modify it without losing its effects.

The reason why I want to know that is because I want to modify this method so I can change the color.
Like this:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.drawString(text1, X1, Y1);
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawString(text2, X2, Y2);
```

It would also help me if someone could tell me where I can find the paintComponent Method in the JavaDoc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [paintComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent-java.awt.Graphics-) method from the javadoc.

You can call the original method by calling `super.paintComponent(g)` within any class that is a children of JComponent.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawString(text1, X1, Y1);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString(text2, X2, Y2);
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

Comment: That means I can't see the lines of code, where the TextPane draws the characters. I've already looked for the paintComponent Method but I couldn't find the parr, where the chara get drawn. I only found the caret drawing line and the part, where the background color gets set.

Comment: Characters are drawn as children of the component. If you want to change the colour of characters in the JTextPane, you need to change their Color attribute. You can do so using an EditorKit.

Comment: You can check there http://javatechniques.com/blog/setting-jtextpane-font-and-color/